# How to dynamically resize parent DIV?

Tags: html, dynamic, resize, css-float, width

Basically I have float divs with fixed width of 250px. I need to make it so that the width of a parent div and the width of the browser resize automatically based on the amount of float divs i add.

For example: if my browser size is 800px wide and i have 2 float divs which combined are 500px wide than there will be no horizontal scroll bars because 500 fits inside 800. But when i add 2 more float divs the total width of all float will be 1000px which is bigger than my browser width thus creating horizontal scroll bars and making the browser resize automatically.

Right now when i try to do it, float divs that dont fint inside 800px just drop down instead of adding on the side.

I could specify fixed width of parent container but the whole point is to make float add to the side dynamically.

Any suggestions? If CSS can't do it maybe Javascript can. 
Is there a Javascript that will explicitly add width to the parent div whenever child divs are added?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `width:reminder;` to the parent DIV.